# Why can't I shutdown running kvm instance?

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, selinux, libvirt, qemu

I have running kvm instance:

```
=# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 2     debian-test                    running
```

When I try to shut it down, I get:

```
=# virsh shutdown debian-test
Domain debian-test is being shutdown
```

But the instance is still running. In logs I found only:

"error : virIdentityGetSystem:173 : Unable to lookup SELinux process context: Invalid argument"

I am not using SELinux, so in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` I changed security_driver to `none`.

Afterwards I destroyed the machine (libvirt destroy ...), restarted libvirt-bin, qemu-system-x86, and restarted the virtual machine - but shutting down is still not possible.

How can it be debugged/fixed? I'm running libvirt on debian host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have acpid installed in the client? A shutdown simply sends a "power button pressed" event to the VM, the VM will need to catch it and actually perform the shutdown.

Comment: There is no system installed there, because I can't connect to it ( wrote about it in http://serverfault.com/questions/567716/virt-install-ignoring-vnc-port-listen ). But there should be debian installation iso running there, and afaik it understands shutdown commands.

Comment: Actually, I do not think the debian installer runs acpid to catch those commands. They tend to keep the installer pretty light. Not entirely sure, though.

Comment: OK. Verified with VirtualBox - you're right. System boots only to grub, and asks to make a choice. Makes sense it doesn't respect acpi there.

Comment: Note that you need both the `acpid` and the `acpi-support-base` packages installed in the guest for `virsh shutdown` to work.